# Deleted pointer still pointing the old data

Tags: c++

I thought the memory where the deleted pointer pointed should be covered with zeros.(not sure )
But it still pointing the int value 10 and same address. What's going on?

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 10;
cout << *p << endl; //10
cout << p << endl;  //0x7fafc3c02e80    
delete p;
cout << *p << endl; //10
cout << &(*p) << endl;  //0x7fafc3c02e80!
return 0;
```

Comment: deleting a pointer doesn't chage the address it was pointing to. It just frees the memory that was once allocated, so it may be used again. Also, dereferencing deleted pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You write your credit card number on a piece of paper.  You crumple it up and throw it in the wastebasket.  Someone else takes it out, uncrumples the paper, and reads your credit card number.  What's going on?  (Not a perfect analogy, in part because in the C++ case there's usually not even any crumpling going on.)

Comment: deleting pointer means [`the memory becomes available again for other requests of dynamic memory.`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

Comment: `*p` after `delete p` is undefined behavior. It might give you a meaningful value once, but next time you try your PC might explode. Just dont do it.

Comment: haha okay,thanks guys. I'll never do it again. But one thing more.Then how it detects if the memory is delete and allow to use? otherwise it's all same as before except it executed `delete` keyword

Comment: It knows the memory is free because it is no longer allocated and so when you next call new it knows that memory is available for allocation and can use it.  If you had not called delete it would not make use of that memory (speaking simply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete operator frees the memory that was pointed to by the pointer. Once free it can be reallocated at any time so accessing that pointer will have unpredictable results.  In your program it is simply the case that the memory has not yet been reallocated for anything else.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6227113.aspx

Specifically:

"Using the delete operator on an object deallocates its memory. A program that dereferences a pointer after the object is deleted can have unpredictable results or crash.
When delete is used to deallocate memory for a C++ class object, the object's destructor is called before the object's memory is deallocated (if the object has a destructor)."

Answer (score 1):

You have returned the space that was allocated to the free heap pool.   That does not mean something is going to write zeros to it.  That takes time, and you might not want to spend that time on that task.

I suppose some types could have destructors that could clear their storage during destruction, but an `int` doesn't.

If you do want data erased, clear it yourself before calling `delete`

It's also a bad idea to continue to use the memory after you've told the system you are done with it.

So you have the option of setting your pointer to `NULL` after the `delete`, that will help cause an exception if you do screw up and try to use the old pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting the actual `value` of the pointer or the value its pointing at. You are just **deallocating the memory** so some other pointer "later" will be able to point at that same spot.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the pointer need not even point to the same spot. The freed memory can just as well be used right in the middle of a subsequent allocation.

Comment: @cad 100% correct. But not for a noob question like this

Comment: A noob questions requires simplifications, so a more imprecise, abstract explanation would be better. Plain incorrectness is harmful to, and especially, noobs.